# How do I display 3 post each in a bootstrap carousel?

Tags: loop

[image]

The following code displays 3 posts in a row which is in class item active.. but how do i display other post in custom post type class item so the carousel slides to display other 3 posts in a row like the image above..

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial','numberposts' => 3 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
$index = 0;?>

<div class="carousel-reviews broun-block">
<div class="container">
<div id="carousel-reviews" class="carousel slide testi" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
<?php foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ++$index; ?>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="block-text rel zmin">
                    <p><?php the_content();?></p>
                    <ins class="ab zmin sprite block"></ins>
                </div>
                <div class="person-text rel">
                    <a title="" href="#"><?php the_title();?></a>
                    <i><?php the_field('country');?></i>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
```

Using while

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'testimonial',
    'posts_per_page' =>-1,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 3,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ):?>
<?php  $j = 0; ?>
<div class="carousel-reviews broun-block">
<div class="container">
<div id="carousel-reviews" class="carousel slide testi" data-ride="carousel">

<div class="carousel-inner">
<?php while ($the_query->have_posts()):$the_query->the_post();?>
<?php if($j  == 0): ?>
<div class="item active">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="block-text rel zmin">
                    <p><?php the_content();?></p>
                    <ins class="ab zmin sprite block"></ins>
                </div>
                <div class="person-text rel">
                    <a title="" href="#"><?php the_title();?></a>
                    <i><?php the_field('country');?></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="item ">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="block-text rel zmin">
                    <p><?php the_content();?>
                        <ins class="ab zmin sprite block"></ins>
                </div>
                <div class="person-text rel">
                    <a title="" href="#"><?php the_title();?></a>
                    <i><?php the_field('country');?></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $j++; ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-reviews" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-reviews" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></span>
</a>
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a working example without WordPress? This sounds like a non-WordPress issue but a jQuery / jQuery Plugin issue.

Comment: the carousel works just fine.. i just want to loop through 3 post each in row  div with class item

Answer (score 0):

A `div` with `class="item"` is used for each carousel slide. But right now your `foreach` loop is inside that div, not outside, so all of your posts are going into one slide.

So just change that bit to:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php foreach ($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata ($post); ++$index; ?>
        <div class="item<?php if ($index == 1) { echo ' active'; } ?>">
            // Your post goes here
        </div> <!-- item -->
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div> <!-- carousel-inner -->
```

And finally, change your query at the top to get as many posts as you want in the carousel, such as 10:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial','numberposts' => 10 );
```

Comment: hi.. i have tried as you said..but the post still display one each at item carousel while i need three post each in a row with class item and slide with active class to it

Comment: I would suggest you then copy and paste the [example Bootstrap carousel code](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel) and make sure that works, and then slowly change it by putting in your post code, making sure it works after each change.

Comment: i have tried using while loop as well.. i have added the code in the question above.. it also display only one post at a time.. would appreciate if you could take a view and help.. i want to display three posts in a single carousel and so on